# CSS not applying to page with "/" in it

Tags: php, html, css, url

**INTRO:**

This might be silly, but I am new to web technologies and at the moment I cant solve this problem. So, I am building online store in which are multiple shops. On homepage there is a button for every shop. By clicking on that button user is redirected to the page of shop details. URL for that page is like this: www.store.com/shop_details.php/XX where XX is the ID of that shop in the MySQL database. I have done the frontend for shop_detaills.php and if URL is without "/XX" then CSS is applied.

**PROBLEM:**

CSS is not applied to the webpage when there is necessary extension to the URL.

**SHORT VERSION**

www.website.com/shop_details.php - *CSS WORKS*

www.website.com/shop_details.php/XX - *CSS DOESNT WORK*

**QUESTION**

What is the cause for this problem? How can I get CSS to work on this page?

Comment: What is the exact path that's used to include the CSS file? Can you include the related markup in your post? It's possible the path is treated as relative to the current address. With the `/XX`, the `shop_details.php` is seen by the browser as a directory name, not a file.

Comment: Check the link and import tags for your CSS files and ensure the file paths start with a **/** (slash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the browser is concerned, `/` separates directories -- it doesn't know that the server is treating `/` after the script name as parameters. If you have relative paths for CSS or JS files in the page, they will be interpreted relative to full directory path in the URL. So if the CSS file is in the same directory as the script, you need to use `href="style.css"` if the URL is `shop_details.php`, but `../style.css` if the URL is `shop_details.php/XX`, and `../../style.css` if it's `shop_details.php/XX/YY`.

One solution is to use an absolute path to the CSS, `href="/style.css"`. Another is to use the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag to tell the browser how to interpret relative paths in the rest of the page:

```
<base href="/shop_details.php">
```

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I have added "/" in front of stylesheet path.